# Deploying JBossApp in weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

I need to migrate Jboss Application to weblogic12c, i dont find any good guide to do this. Ok, i create a weblogic.xml for the application, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

And in my web.xml i have configured the welcome page, like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

after this i tryied deploy, and success, no problems, no errors, nothing. In the weblogic panel, the application is running OK, but, when i tried to access any page, return the 404 Error. I dont know why. I need to do another configuration ? Have a good guide to do this migration/deploy ?

Comment: There is not context-root in your weblogic.xml so WebLogic generated it's own base URL which might not be what you intended. Did you check out the URL as WebLogic generated it in the admin console -> your application deployment -> in the "Testing" tab?

Comment: yes, i checked it, the generated route is, localhost:7001/projectname/index.jsp

Comment: You know a complete and easy guide/tutorial to learn how can i migrate this ?

Comment: Java enterprise apps should run on any certified application server. The deployment is in "running" state?

Comment: yes, i read the logs, and i suspect the reason is a external authentication server off application is unvaible, and i think this reason can cause this error. I tryied deploy another app, and success. So, Thank you for helping me, i will investigate more about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logs of weblogic in the path:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/wls12213/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/server/logs

i see an error of comunication with the webApi, and this cause the error 404 with no exception in weblogic.